# CONVERT button not showing in Lead tab in Lightning experience

Tags: lightning, convert

I have added the Convert button in the Mobile & Lightning Actions  and it is still not showing in the Lightning experience but it is in Classic

Answer (score 0):

A lot of times this is because you might not have permission shown in the below screenshot for your profiles

[image]

In your metadata also make sure to check for the existence of [PlatformActionList](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_layouts.htm) metadata item that is associated with a page layout.

Your metadata should have something like below when you retrieve using an IDE (like visual studio extension pack for Salesforce) if it is missing you will need to manually add them

```
 <platformActionList>
    <actionListContext>Record</actionListContext>
    <platformActionListItems>
        <actionName>Convert</actionName>
        <actionType>StandardButton</actionType>
        <sortOrder>1</sortOrder>
    </platformActionListItems>
```